# Is it okay to restart the CRM Asynchronous Processing Service at any time?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I just finished registering a custom workflow with the plugin registration tool. My custom workflow shows up in the possible steps I can choose when creating a workflow, but when I select it I get a generic "An error has occurred" (with the "Download Log File" button grayed out).

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854740/why-do-we-need-to-restart-the-crm-server-after-registering-the-custom-workflow-u) I gathered that I need to restart the CRM Asynchronous Processing Service. Is this something I can do at any time? E.g. will any information or running workflows be lost, or will those be picked up again once it is restarted?

Our server admin also told me there are two such services, one with "Maintenance" in its name. Do both need to be restarted?

Or is my problem not even related to this?
Thanks for any  help. I'm pretty new to CRM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about Campey's issue with the service needing to be manually restarted, but I wouldn't fear about the workflows having data integrity issues if you restart the service.

Windows Services have to handle events to work properly, one of which is the shutdown requested event.  The CRM asynchronous service will stop taking on new work, and do it's best to allow the currently executing workflows to finish up whatever it's working on before stopping.

I would be more concerned about time sensitive steps not being executed with the CRM asynchronous service stopped, than I would be with the CRM asynchronous service's currently executing steps being corrupted.

Comment: As long as I don't really have any time sensitive (an email can wait a minute until the service is done restarting to be sent) I should be fine? Excellent.

Comment: @G_M if you're concerned you could make a workflow activity that updates an entity with the value "Started", sleeps for a minute, and then updates it again to "Finished".  Start the workflow, and then kill the service, and see if the "Finished" value ever gets updated just to prove that steps are finished  "nicely"

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the CRM Async Service stops by itself frequently and needs to be restarted manually and I haven't found any issues with a restart regarding the loss of data.

EDIT: I have found in some high use, multiple server CRM setups that the async service can get "confused" and it will basically try three times and then stop (restoring a large CRM tenant seems to REALLY upset the async). This does not have a negative effect on the system because all jobs are just added to a backlog which runs next time the service is started.

If there is an issue with the Async service it can cause a backlog of items such as Workflows that need to run so restarting can be beneficial.

You can try restarting the service and it MAY solve your problem however can you provide more information about your custom workflow?

Comment: It stops a lot for me too. Once restarted some jobs seem to be run twice causing duplication.